# Finding comments using java expressions

Tags: java, regex, expression

I'm working on an expression that finds comments which begin with % and end with \n or \r and also multiple line comments /* */.  I'm running into trouble for the one beginning with %.  I can get it to detect when the comment starts but it is not terminating with a new line.

`"(%.*\\n\\r)|(/\\*(?:.|[\\n\\r])*?\\*/)"`

For example, if I have

```
%hello

nothing nothing nothing

fi
```

It takes the nothing nothing nothing line as a comment but not the fi line.  I'm so confused.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but this site is really helpful for playing with RegEx in real time: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
((?:%.*?[\\n\\r])|(?:/\\*(?:.|[\\n\\r])*?\\*/))
```

See here: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DGrLAzLEn0)

Or with Pattern.DOTALL

```
(?s)((?:%[^\\n\\r]*)|(?:/\\*.*?\\*/))
```

Comment: Your welcome. Btw. if an answer is solving your problem you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html